# Django: What is a permission codename?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to set up a permissions decorator in my Django app. The docs mention it and nowhere could I find explained what this `codename` represents (a model field? a model method? a permissions method?).

What is the codename and where can I setup codenames?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#the-permission-required-decorator

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can add custom permissions to any model under `Meta` class. Those permission name are called `codename`. It goes like this:

```
class Dish(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ('can_approve_dish', "Can approve Dish publication"),
            ('can_delete_dish', "Can Delete Dish")
        )
```

Here, `can_approve_dish` is a *codename*. Now, to perform any operation on Dish, you can check for permission like this:

```
# Assuming Dish model is under app named - `'app'`
if user.has_perm('app.can_delete_dish'):
    dish.delete()
```

These permissions would be available on admin site to be assigned to users after migration. So, if you haven't assigned a `can_delete_dish` permission to a user, he won't be able to delete that dish.

If you've added different permissions on multiple models under the app named - `app`, all those permissions will come under name `app`. That means, you've to have unique codename across models in the same app.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a bit more sense. But it's still not clear where `can_approve_dish` is defined or what it executes. I assume there is a permissions file with a `DishPermissions` class with a method called `can_approve_dish`?

Comment: @Proto It's not a method, it's just a identifier for the permission. Django adds all the permissions in `auth_permissions` table.  And all permission binding to user is added in `user_permissions` table. Check this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#topic-authorization

Comment: So it seems the codename is literally an arbitrary name that's used as a check for an as yet undefined action. It's not attached to any permission that's already defined persay. Is this correct? Your reference to 'the permission' doesn't really clear up *what* permission and how I can attach a list of codenames to specific actions. The docs don't really make this any clearer for me either. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Proto Yes, that's an arbitrary name only. You can choose any name you like, that follows python naming convention.

Comment: Having the same issue understanding as OP. Every doc/reference tells how to declare these perms or check for perms, but does not tell how to dictate what these permission names accomplish. Shouldnt there be a function somewhere for the representing the permission?